# How is Tie::IxHash implemented in Perl?

Tags: perl

I've recently come upon a situation in Perl where the use of an order-preserving hash would make my code more readable and easier to use. After a bit of searching, I found out about the Tie::IxHash CPAN module, which does exactly what I want. Before I throw caution to the wind and just start using it though, I'd like to get a better idea of how it works and what kind of performance I can expect from it.

From what I know, ordered associative arrays are usually implemented as tries, which I've never actually used before, but do know that their performance falls in line with my expectations (I expect to do a lot of reading and writing, and will need to always remember the order keys were *originally* inserted). My problem is I can't figure out if this is how Tie::IxHash was made, or what sort of performance I should expect from it, or whether there's some better/cleaner option for me (I'd really rather not keep a separate array and hash to accomplish what I need as this produces ugly code and space inefficiency). I'm also just curious for curiosity's sake. If it wasn't implemented as a trie, how was it implemented? I know I can wade at the source code, but I'm hoping someone else has already done this, and I'm guessing that I'm not the only person who'll be interested in the answer.

So... Ideas? Suggestions? Advice?

Comment: See also moritz's ie::Hash::Indexed (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::Hash::Indexed), which describes itself as similar to Tie::IxHash, but written in XS and about twices as fast.

Comment: I tried this out and it accomplished everything I needed faster than IxHash. Sadly, it's not installed in the library on the server I'm forced to use, and I've been told I'm not allowed to install it, so I'm stuck with Tie::IxHash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aIxHash) object is implemented in a direct fashion, using the regular Perl building blocks that one would expect. Specifically, such an object is a blessed array reference holding 4 elements.

- `[0]` A hash reference to store the keys of the user's hash. This is used any time the module needs to check for the existence of a key.
- `[1]` An array reference to store the keys of the user's hash, in order.
- `[2]` A parallel array reference to store the values, also in order.
- `[3]` An integer to keep track of the current position within the two parallel arrays. This is needed for iteration.

Regarding performance, a good [benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark) is usually worth more than speculation. My guess is that the biggest performance hit will come with deletion, because the arrays holding the ordered keys and values will require adjustment.

Comment: I did a bit of investigation and benchmarking on my own, and thought mentioning the results here might be useful. Basically, all normal hash operations are O(1), except delete which is O(n) and gets very slow when you're dealing with big hashes as the entire [0] hash past the deleted item needs to be reordered. Shifting is even slower as it runs at theta(n) (always requiring n iterations). All other standard array and hash operations I looked at were O(1), so basically, as long as you're not deleting or shifting (find a way to use push instead), it's a pretty good module to use.

Answer (score 1):

The [source](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Tie-IxHash-1.22/lib/Tie/IxHash.pm) will tell you how this functionality is implemented and measurement it's performance.

Comment: I specifically stated in my question that I thought it would be useful to me and to others with the same question to have the answer discussed here. I know I can wade through the source for it, but this strikes me as something that should really be more easily available to people. If I were the module's author, I would have put it in the documentation, but since I'm not, discussing here was my next best choice.

Comment: Then just look at the first 60 lines. That will tell you 90% of what you want to know.

Comment: But wouldn't it be better if we just had 100% of what I want to know here instead of cluttering up the topic with answers and comments I already noted I'm aware of in the original question?

Comment: But wouldn't it be better if we just had 100% of what I want to know here instead of cluttering up the topic with answers and comments I already noted I'm aware of in the original question?