# Does C++ have ordered hash?

Tags: c++, perl

Perl has a structure called *"ordered hash"* `Tie::IxHash`. One can use it as a hashtable/map. The entries are in the order of insertion.

Wonder if there is such a thing in C++.

Here is a sample Perl snippet:

```
use Tie::IxHash;

tie %food_color, "Tie::IxHash";
$food_color{Banana} = "Yellow";
$food_color{Apple}  = "Green";
$food_color{Lemon}  = "Yellow";

print "In insertion order, the foods are:\n";
foreach $food (keys %food_color) {
    print "  $food\n"; #will print the entries in order
}
```

**Update 1**

As @kerrek-sb pointed out, one can use Boost Multi-index Containers Library.  Just wonder if it is possible to do it with STL.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Boost.Multiindex.

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know. Wonder it's available in plain C++11.

Comment: What's that supposed to mean? It's a C++ library, so you can use it with C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's supposed to mean, without the Boost.Multiindex dependency. In some environments it is not easy to introduce external dependencies which must then be updated and kept track of.

Comment: Boost is as close to the standard library as you get without being in it. Its considered the testing ground for classes to be considered for standardization. And its header only so minimal dependencies.

Comment: @LokiAstari *Boost itself* is an external dependency.

Comment: @immibis: I totally agree. I am just arguing that you can't get closer to standard than boost.

Comment: Comment on the update: Not directly with one container. But with the combination of a vector and map (or unordered_map) you can achieve the same results relatively easily.

Comment: @LokiAstari: There's a big difference. C++11 is something you can rely on, while boost is subject to change (which is a pain). Not using boost myself, but from what I gather that also happens frequently.

Comment: @codingFun: Do you need support for deletion? (That would make things harder, because you could insert infinitely many items so an insertion counter would overflow at some point)

Comment: Thanks @jo-so for asking, should have mentioned that I need deletion as well.

Comment: Could you give more requirements about the container? Do you just need an ordered associative container, or do you want constant-time lookups combined with ordered iteration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A std::map that keep track of the order of insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no. No, there's no one that that's specifically intended to provide precisely the same functionality. But yes, you can do the same in a couple of different ways. If you expect to access the data primarily in the order inserted, then the obvious way to go would be a simple vector of pairs:

```
std::vector<std::string, std::string> food_colors;

food_colors.push_back({"banana", "yellow"});
food_colors.push_back({"apple", "green"});
food_colors.push_back({"lemon", "yellow"});

for (auto const &f : food_colors)
    std::cout << f.first << ": " << f.second << "\n";
```

This preserves order by simply storing the items in order. If you need to access them by key, you can use `std::find` to do a linear search for a particular item. That minimizes extra memory used, at the expense of slow access by key if you get a lot of items.

If you want faster access by key with a large number of items, you could use a Boost MultiIndex. If you really want to avoid that, you can create an index of your own pretty easily. To do this, you'd start by inserting your items into a  `std::unordered_map` (or perhaps an `std::map`). This gives fast access by key, but no access in insertion order. It does, however, return an iterator to each items as it's inserted into the map. You can simply store those iterators into a vector to get access in the order of insertion. Although the principle of this is fairly simple, the code is a bit on the clumsy side, to put it nicely:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> fruit;
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator> in_order;

in_order.push_back(fruit.insert(std::make_pair("banana", "yellow")).first);
in_order.push_back(fruit.insert(std::make_pair("apple", "green")).first);
in_order.push_back(fruit.insert(std::make_pair("lemon", "yellow")).first);
```

This allows access either by key:

```
// ripen the apple:
fruit["apple"] = "red";
```

...or in insertion order:

```
for (auto i : in_order)
    std::cout << i->first << ": " << i->second << "\n";
```

For the moment, I've shown the basic mechanism for doing this--if you wanted to use it much, you'd probably want to wrap that up into a nice class to hide some of the ugliness and the keep things pretty and clean in normal use.

Comment: Using a vector to store the order will require O(n) complexity to erase an arbitrary key. This may not be a problem in practice, but this limitation does exist e.g. in Python's `OrderedDict`. (I haven't checked how `Tie::IxHash` implements deletion.)

Comment: Thanks @jerry-coffin for the detailed answer and everyone for the discussion. I understand it better now. By the way, I saw this thread on `Tie::IxHash` that it's not efficient in the case of deletion.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344512/how-is-tieixhash-implemented-in-perl

Comment: In the first case (vector of pairs) I think it's possible to use std::lower_bound to get the index of the element you're looking for by iterating over the keys, which is a binary search.

Comment: @ChatterOne: Unfortunately, no. `lower_bound` requires that the collection be sorted by key, and the whole point here is that it retains the order of insertion rather than being ordered by keys.

Comment: @JerryCoffin You're right of course, I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

An associative container that remembers insertion order does not come with the C++ standard library, but it is straightforward to implement one using existing STL containers.

For example, a combination of `std::map` (for fast lookup) and `std::list` (to maintain key ordering) can be used to emulate an insertion-ordered map. Here is an example that demonstrates the idea:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename K, typename V>
class InsOrderMap {
  struct value_pos {
    V value;
    typename std::list<K>::iterator pos_iter;
    value_pos(V value, typename std::list<K>::iterator pos_iter):
      value(value), pos_iter(pos_iter) {}
  };

  std::list<K> order;
  std::unordered_map<K, value_pos> map;

  const value_pos& locate(K key) const {
    auto iter = map.find(key);
    if (iter == map.end())
      throw std::out_of_range("key not found");
    return iter->second;
  }

public:
  void set(K key, V value) {
    auto iter = map.find(key);
    if (iter != map.end()) {
      // no order change, just update value
      iter->second.value = value;
      return;
    }
    order.push_back(key);
    map.insert(std::make_pair(key, value_pos(value, --order.end())));
  }

  void erase(K key) {
    order.erase(locate(key).pos_iter);
    map.erase(key);
  }

  V operator[](K key) const {
    return locate(key).value;
  }

  // iterate over the mapping with a function object
  // (writing a real iterator is too much code for this example)
  template<typename F>
  void walk(F fn) const {
    for (auto key: order)
      fn(key, (*this)[key]);
  }
};

// TEST

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
  typedef InsOrderMap<std::string, std::string> IxHash;

  IxHash food_color;
  food_color.set("Banana", "Yellow");
  food_color.set("Apple", "Green");
  food_color.set("Lemon", "Yellow");

  assert(food_color["Banana"] == std::string("Yellow"));
  assert(food_color["Apple"] == std::string("Green"));
  assert(food_color["Lemon"] == std::string("Yellow"));

  auto print = [](std::string k, std::string v) {
    std::cout << k << ' ' << v << std::endl;
  };
  food_color.walk(print);
  food_color.erase("Apple");
  std::cout << "-- without apple" << std::endl;
  food_color.walk(print);
  return 0;
}
```

Developing this code into a drop-in replacement for a full-fledged container such as `std::map` requires considerable effort.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342 for the detailed answer too.

Answer (score -4):

C++ has standard containers for this.  An *unordered map* seems like what you are looking for:

```
std::unordered_map <std::string, std::string> mymap = {{"Banana", "Yellow" }, {"Orange","orange" } }
```

Comment: An unordered map is, most obviously, unordered. The regular std::map is based on trees and not a hash table, such that the operations can no longer be performed in O(1), but only O(log N). Therefore there is no equivalent standard data structure.